# How do you print received cookie info to stdout with curl?

Tags: bash, unix, cookies, curl

How do you print received cookie info to stdout with curl?

According to the man pages if you use '-' as the file name for the -c --cookie-jar option it should print the cookie to stdout. The problem is I get an error:

```
curl: option -: is unknown
```

an example of the command I am running:

```
curl -c --cookie-jar - 'http://google.com'
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You get that error because you use in the wrong way that option. When you see in a man page an option like:

```
-c, --cookie-jar <file name>
```

this mean that if you want to use that option, you must to use `-c` ***OR*** `--cookie-jar`, never both! These two are equivalent and, in fact, `-c` is the abbreviated form for `--cookie-jar`. There are many, many options in man pages which are designed in the same way.

In your case:

```
curl -c - 'http://google.com'
```

`--cookie-jar` is given as argument for `-c` option, so, it's interpreted as a file name, not like an option (as you may think), and `-` remains alone which leads to error because `curl`, indeed, doesn't have such an option.

Answer (score 24):

You can save the cookies received and send them back to the server using the following commands:

1) To get/save the cookies to file "/tmp/cookies.txt":

```
curl -c /tmp/cookies.txt http://the.site.with.cookies/
```

2) To send the cookies back to the server (again using file "/tmp/cookies.txt"):

```
curl -b /tmp/cookies.txt http://the.site.with.cookies/
```

I hope it was useful.

[]s
Ronaldo

Answer (score 21):

Remove the "-c"

```
curl --cookie-jar - 'http://google.com'
```

Also you try verbose mode and see the cookie headers:

```
curl -v 'http://google.com'
```

Answer (score 20):

You need to use two options to get only the cookie text on stdout:

`--cookie-jar <file name>` from the man page:

> If you set the file name to a single dash, '-', the cookies will be written to stdout.

`--output <file>` from the man page:

> Write output to  instead of stdout.

Set it to `/dev/null` to throw it away.

`--silent` is also helpful.

Putting it all together:

```
curl --silent --output /dev/null --cookie-jar - 'http://www.google.com/'
```

Output:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

#HttpOnly_.google.com   TRUE    /   FALSE   1512524163  NID 105=DownH33BKZnCsWJeGvsIC5cKRi7CPT3K3QjfUB-4js5xGw6P_6svMqU1yKlKOEu4XwL_TdddZlcMITefFGOtCCyzJNhO_7E9UMNpbQHja40IAerYP5Bwj-FhY1m35mZdvkVSmrg1pZPvH96IkVVVVVVVV
```

My use case: Test that your website uses the `HttpOnly` cookie setting, per the OWASP recommendation:

```
curl --silent --output /dev/null --cookie-jar - 'http://www.google.com/' | grep HttpOnly
```